# What is the physical significance of a polytropic index between 0 and 1?

Tags: thermodynamics

For polytropic process $PV^n=C$ where $n=(1-\gamma)K+\gamma \,$  I understand the physical significance of all the values of $n$ other than between $0$ and $1$.
There is clear information for the other cases [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytropic_process#Relationship_to_ideal_processes) but it just skips over this case.

Answer (score 1):

When the index $n$ occurs between $0$ and $1$ it means that the polytropic curve will lie between the curve for an isobaric process and the curve for an isothermal process.